# Modify the state using returned variable (Array.push)

Tags: storage, memory

In my contact I want to have one place where I find an existing object(struct) and then use it in multiple places to read and modify it - but seems like it's not possible?

```solidity
contract A
{
    struct Prop
    {
    }

    struct App
    {
        Prop[] props;
    }

    App[] apps;

    function AddProp(string memory name) public
    {
        App memory a = FindApp(name);

        if(bytes(a.name).length > 0)
            a.props.push(Prop()); // TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but "storage" was given.

        else
            revert('Application not found');        
    }

    function FindApp(string memory name) public returns (App memory) // can't return 'storage'
    {
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < apps.length; i++)
        {
            if(apps[i].name == name)
            {
                return apps[i];
            }
        }

        return App();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change quite a few things to get this code to compile, but the important piece you were missing is that *public* functions can't return storage references (because an external caller couldn't do anything with that), but *internal* (or private) functions can:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.11;

contract A
{
    struct Prop
    {
        uint256 foo; // empty structs are not allowed
    }

    struct App
    {
        string name; // added this because it was used elsewhere
        Prop[] props;
    }

    App[] apps;

    function AddProp(string memory name) public
    {
        App storage a = FindApp(name); // storage

        if(bytes(a.name).length > 0)
            a.props.push(Prop(0));
        else
            revert('Application not found');        
    }

    function FindApp(string memory name) internal view returns (App storage) // storage
    {
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(name));
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < apps.length; i++)
        {
            // string equality is not defined, have to compare hashes
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(apps[i].name)) == hash)
            {
                return apps[i];
            }
        }

        revert("Not found."); // Wasn't sure what to do here... you can't just return a new App because you need to return something from storage
    }
}
```